# VM crash with maven-surefire-plugin having module-info.java

Tags: java, maven-surefire-plugin, module-info

Initially I had one unique module-info in the next folder:
`src/main/java/module-info.java`.

I was able to run the tests successfully.

Now I need to overwrite the `module-info` because I need to add some changes that are relevant only for the test. The change is about opening the module. I am adding this new `module-info.java` here:
`src/main/test/module-info.java`.

If I execute the tests with that, I get the next error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) on project myProject: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject && /home/xxxxxx/programs/java/jdk-11.0.10/bin/java --add-reads org.eclipse.yasson=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens org.eclipse.yasson/org.eclipse.yasson.internal.cdi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports org.eclipse.yasson/org.eclipse.yasson.internal.cdi=java.naming @/home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject/target/surefire/surefireargs1904933309274673454 /home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject/target/surefire 2021-03-15T16-59-30_852-jvmRun1 surefire12108354424712784981tmp surefire_06907989403807941803tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject && /home/xxxxxx/programs/java/jdk-11.0.10/bin/java --add-reads org.eclipse.yasson=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens org.eclipse.yasson/org.eclipse.yasson.internal.cdi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports org.eclipse.yasson/org.eclipse.yasson.internal.cdi=java.naming @/home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject/target/surefire/surefireargs1904933309274673454 /home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject/target/surefire 2021-03-15T16-59-30_852-jvmRun1 surefire12108354424712784981tmp surefire_06907989403807941803tmp
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:690)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:248)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1217)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1063)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:889)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

There is a new file created in `target/surefire-reports/2021-03-15T16-59-30_852-jvmRun1.dumpstream`:

```
# Created at 2021-03-15T16:59:31.842
Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. Stream 'Error occurred during initialization of boot layer'.

# Created at 2021-03-15T16:59:31.854
Corrupted STDOUT by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. Stream 'java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: /home/xxxxxx/workspace/myProject/target/test-classes'.
```

This is the module-info in the test folder:

```
open module org.eclipse.yasson {
    
    requires jakarta.json;
    requires jakarta.json.bind;
    requires java.logging;
    requires org.junit.jupiter.api;
    requires static jakarta.annotation;
    requires static java.naming;
    requires static java.sql;
    requires static java.desktop;
    requires static jakarta.cdi;

    exports org.eclipse.yasson;
    exports org.eclipse.yasson.spi;
    provides jakarta.json.bind.spi.JsonbProvider with org.eclipse.yasson.JsonBindingProvider;
    uses org.eclipse.yasson.spi.JsonbComponentInstanceCreator;
}
```

maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4

java version "11.0.10"

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that there were some tests in the default package (no package). After updating `maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5` I was able to see this.

Comment: yes, because i implemented this feature that specific line in dump file is somuch important that must be printed on the console.